# Do I need to use Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word to create a report in Word?

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I cannot seem to understand if I need Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word and how to get it. I know that it works together with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word as seen in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx), for example:

> Visual Studio extends the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmark
> object by providing the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Bookmark host
> control. The Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Bookmark host control behaves
> like a native Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmark, but has
> additional events and data-binding capabilities. You can bind data to
> a bookmark control on a document in the same way that you bind data to
> a text box control on a Windows Form. For more information, see
> Bookmark Control.

and that it enables you to add controls to a word document [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.controls(v=vs.120).aspx), but I am not sure what the added value is (or if  I need it).

I am developing an application that will generate a report of cyber security risks in a company (with primarily text and tables), and I am wondering what I have to use to make sure I can create my report properly (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word at the least).

Also, I do not really understand where to get the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word from. I included the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word from NuGet easily, but I cannot find the other one in either NuGet or the Reference Manager. Because of this, I can not play around with this extra functionality and determine whether I need it in my project or not.

If you need more detail about my project to answer this question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to do Office Interop. Note that doing Office Interop requires you to have Office installed, also on the PC where you finally want to use it.

For a DOCX report, there are libraries like [docx by XCeed](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX) (formerly a Github repo by the same author of [docx on Codeplex](https://docx.codeplex.com/)) which can do things a lot easier. However, not all features might be supported.

Comment: And also Office Interop is not supported or licensed for a server application (unclear if that's the case here).

Comment: it's a client application, and the pc's that it will be used on already have Office anyways. That's why I though Office Interop would be a good idea. The main focus of my question was if I need the Office Tools.

Comment: Update : if anyone try to reach Codeplex sorry to say this but"
On March 31, 2017, Microsoft announced the discontinuation of CodePlex. The original plan was to make CodePlex read-only in October 2017 before finally shutting it down on December 15, 2017. Microsoft partnered with GitHub to allow projects to be migrated to the service."

Comment: @ManojKumar: I've updated the link. The original author is out. The software was taken over by Xceed meanwhile, but they still have a free version

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thank You for the info and have a doubt whether XCeed leaves WM in the Word Document after Exporting it